# Custom fabricJS object not restoring properly with fromObject method

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to serialize/deserialize a custom farbicJS object that is subclassed from `fabric.Textbox`, but when loading the object back into the canvas from the saved JSON, the custom object gets restored with the wrong attributes, and it no longer behaves the way that it should when resizing the object.

Here is my custom object that is used to create a textbox with padding, and `fromObject` method I tried to use below:

EDITED: I fixed the initial height issue by refactoring the toObject method to include `_renderBackground` and `padding`

```
fabric.TextboxWithPadding = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Textbox, {
        type: 'TextboxWithPadding',

        _renderBackground: function (ctx) {
            if (!this.backgroundColor) {
                return;
            }
            var dim = this._getNonTransformedDimensions();
            ctx.fillStyle = this.backgroundColor;

            ctx.fillRect(
                -dim.x / 2 - this.padding,
                -dim.y / 2 - this.padding,
                dim.x + this.padding * 2,
                dim.y + this.padding * 2
            );

            this._removeShadow(ctx);
        },
        toObject: function () {
            return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
                _renderBackground: this._renderBackground,
                padding: this.padding
            });
        },
    });

    fabric.TextboxWithPadding.fromObject = function (object, callback) {
        return fabric.Object._fromObject("TextboxWithPadding", object, callback, 'text');
    };
```

When adding the `TextboxWithPadding` I am using the following:

```
if (drawingObject.type === "label") {
            canvas.selection = false;
            var pointer = canvas.getPointer(options.e);
            origX = pointer.x;
            origY = pointer.y;
            label = new fabric.TextboxWithPadding('New Label', {
                selectable: true,
                fill: '#555555',
                left: origX,
                top: origY,
                lockRotation: true,
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: 400,
                backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                textAlign: 'center',
                fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
                padding: 10
            })

            label.setControlsVisibility({
                mt: false,
                bl: false,
                br: false,
                tl: false,
                tr: false,
                mb: true,
            });

            canvas.add(label);

            let lastHeight;
            let calcFont;

            const updateTextSize = () => {

                const controlPoint = label.__corner;

                //mr and ml are the only controlPoints that don't modify textbox height
                if (controlPoint && controlPoint != "mr" && controlPoint != "ml") {
                    lastHeight = label.height * label.scaleY;
                    calcFont = lastHeight * .8
                    if (calcFont < 10) {
                        calcFont = 10
                    }
                } else {
                    lastHeight = label.height
                    calcFont = label.fontSize
                }

                label.set({
                    height: lastHeight || label.height,
                    scaleY: 1,
                    scaleX: 1,
                    fontSize: calcFont
                });
                canvas.renderAll();
            };

            label.on('scaling', updateTextSize);

            // Handle textbox content updates
            canvas.on('text:changed', function () {
                label.set('width', label.width)
                $(".deleteBtn").remove();
            });

            canvas.on('mouse:up', function (options) {
                if (drawingObject.type === "label") {
                    drawingObject.type = ''
                }
                canvas.renderAll();
                canvas.selection = true;
            });
        }
```

Here is the result of saving this object to JSON (excluding the backgroundImage data url):

```
{"version":"2.4.0","objects":[{"type":"TextboxWithPadding","version":"2.4.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":49.5,"top":49,"width":100,"height":20.34,"fill":"#555555","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"#ffffff","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"text":"New Label","fontSize":18,"fontWeight":400,"fontFamily":"Open Sans","fontStyle":"normal","lineHeight":1.16,"underline":false,"overline":false,"linethrough":false,"textAlign":"center","textBackgroundColor":"","charSpacing":0,"minWidth":20,"styles":{}}]}
```

You can see how the height changes from the default 100 to 20.34 as well. I'm thinking that the event handlers need to be added to the custom object when it is loaded back into the canvas, but I'm not entirely sure.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after messing around with this some more, I figured it out.

I needed to add in my custom methods and properties to `toObject` class method like so:

```
// ...
toObject: function () {
            return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
                _renderBackground: this._renderBackground,
                padding: this.padding,
            });
        },
// ...
```

and to add the listeners back to the restored object I added a 'reviver function' as the thrid argument to `canvas.loadFromJSON` which allows me to access the objects added to the canvas from JSON:

```
$("#load-from-json").click(function () {
        canvas.loadFromJSON(
            JSON.parse(canvasSavedJSON),
            canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
            function (o, object) {
                if (object.type == 'TextboxWithPadding') {
                    object.setControlsVisibility({
                        mt: false,
                        bl: false,
                        br: false,
                        tl: false,
                        tr: false,
                        mb: true,
                    });

                    let lastHeight;
                    let calcFont;

                    const updateTextSize = () => {

                        const controlPoint = object.__corner;

                        //mr and ml are the only controlPoints that dont modify textbox height
                        if (controlPoint && controlPoint != "mr" && controlPoint != "ml") {
                            lastHeight = object.height * object.scaleY;
                            calcFont = lastHeight * .8
                            if (calcFont < 10) {
                                calcFont = 10
                            }
                        } else {
                            lastHeight = object.height
                            calcFont = object.fontSize
                        }

                        object.set({
                            height: lastHeight || object.height,
                            scaleY: 1,
                            scaleX: 1,
                            //padding: lastHeight,
                            fontSize: calcFont
                        });
                        canvas.renderAll();
                    };
                    object.on('scaling', updateTextSize);
                }
            }
        );
    });
```